# Dart Mixin get super field value

Tags: dart, mixins

Based on a class and a mixin

```
class CounterModel extends MVAModel with CounterModelGeneratedCode {
  int counter = 2;
}

mixin CounterModelGeneratedCode on MVAModel {

int get counter => store.get("counter", () => (super as CounterModel).counter);
set counter(int value) => store.set("counter", value);
}
```

The dart analyzer does not complain but on compilation I get an

> Error: Can't use 'super' as an expression. To delegate a constructor
> to a super constructor, put the super call as an initializer.

How can I access the overshadowed values of the CounterModel class (e.g. 2 for counter)?

Comment: Your mental model seems backward. The mixin inserts a superclass that `CounterModel` derives from. `CounterModel` is the most derived class in your inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, and the analyzer should have caught the syntax error too.
You cannot override the resolution of super-invocations, you can only call the actual superclass member.
Also, the `counter` is *not* on the superclass, which is `MVAModel`, so using `super` is not the right approach.

You could try `(this as CounterModel).counter`, which would work, but it isn't optimal. The cast is not necessary, we can do better.

What you probably want in this case is to add a definition of the `counter` variable to the `mixin` declaration:

```dart
 abstract int counter;
```

That way, it requires classes mixing it in to define such a counter (which the one class doing so then does).
Then you can invoke the counter in the mixin as just `this.counter`.